# PHP: different quotes?

Tags: php, quotes

What is the difference between the quotes " and ' ? What about `? Is there an error in using different quotes ' and " below?

```
 $result = pg_query_params($dbconn,
      'INSERT INTO users 
      (username, email, passhash_md5)
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3)',
          array($username, $email, $passhash_md5
      )


      $result = pg_query_params( $dbconn,
          "SELECT user_id
           FROM users
          WHERE email = $1",
          array( $email )
          )
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Variable-substitution isn't done when using single quotes ('), meaning that the values in your first example would literally be $1 $2 etc if it was a regular string and not passed on to a function that replaces them.

If you don't need variable-substitiution, it's better to stick with single quotes for performance reasons.

`` invokes the shell-engine and invokes it as an actual command, and returning the result, just like in perl. Hence, it has a completely different meaning.

examples:

```
$email = 'user@example.org';
$sql1 = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = $email";
$sql2 = 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = $email';
```

$sql1 would be SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = user@example.org

$sql2 would be SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = $email

Comment: Escapes to control chars, like \n and \t are not expanded in single quote strings, too.

Comment: Strings like `$sql1` always make me cringe. If you _really_ want to include a variable in it, using `{$email}` always gets my preference. My usual approach: `"WHERE email = ".$email`, wich makes it absolutely clear that it is NOT to be taken literally.

Comment: Of course none of those ways are safe against SQL injection, whatever you call the variable! The OP has it right, using $1 et al to pg_query_params in single quotes; no variable-substitution is actually occurring here. The ‘$1’ syntax is perhaps a little misleading... other query parameterisation systems just use ‘?’.

Comment: PHP tokenizes input text using a state machine ([like this](http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_3/lcov_html/var/php_gcov/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_language_parser.c.gcov.php)), so **there is absolutely no performance difference between single and double quotes** when you don't use variable interpolation. Also, it's not cool to show example code that has serious security holes in it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `"` lets you embed variables like so:

```
<?php
$beer = 'Heineken';
echo "$beer's taste is great"; // works; "'" is an invalid character for variable names
echo "He drank some $beers";   // won't work; 's' is a valid character for variable names but the variable is "$beer"
echo "He drank some ${beer}s"; // works
echo "He drank some {$beer}s"; // works
?>
```

(From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc))

Using `'` means that no checking for variables is done.

```
<?php
echo '$beer';
?>
```

Would output `$beer`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between single and double quoted strings is well explained in the [PHP manual about Strings](http://ca.php.net/types.string).

In your example, since you are using substitution variables such as `$1` that mean something specific to `pg_query_params` and that you do *not* want PHP to interpret as variable names, you should use single quotes for your SQL query strings.