# Connecting PHP to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

```
<?php
$serverName = "(local)"; //serverName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DabaseNew", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"*****");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn==true ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if(!$stmt){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)){
    echo $obj->Description.", ".$obj->lName."<br />";
}
?>
```

I am trying to connect to php to my sql server using sqlsrv_connect. The above code gives me an error below;

Output:
Connection established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SERVICES'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'SERVICES'. ) )

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee` 

**Is that query ?**

Comment: What do you want to select from which database under which conditions?

Comment: @Abdullah I would like to see all columns of the table

Comment: what'S the name of the table you are querying?

Comment: @Daniel I want to see the Description field and Last Name field so i use "SELECT Description, Last Name FROM Dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee" but it still not working

Comment: the table name is "Dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee"

Comment: Are you sure you table name contains spaces?

Comment: What kind of that tablename

Comment: I think you meant: `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee]';` if your table name is `DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee`

Comment: @Gudgip i try sqlserver is allows that but why someone use table name like that

Comment: No idea why, probably a bad database design..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` character with `\$`, as php treats it as first character ov a variable. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES\$Employee]";
```

---

EDIT:

To avoid escapingg you could also use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`. Then PHP does not resolve variables within the string. ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402566/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php))

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee]';
```

---

2nd EDIT:

To concatenate two strings use `.` operator like this:

```
$foo = "Hello ";
$bar = $foo."world!"; // gives "Hello world!"
```

As you can read within the answer linked within the first edit `"` double quotes resolve variables inbetween, while `'` single quotes don't. your possible solution could be like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT [First Name] AS firstName, [Last Name] AS lastName
            FROM  Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee]
            WHERE [Employee Number] = 15 OR [E-Mail] = \''.mssql_escape($mail).'\'';
```

But you should NEVER directly send a GET parameter top your sql server. Anybody could infiltrate your database or even delete it. Therefore you should add a escape function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574805/how-to-escape-strings-in-sql-server-using-php) or consider using another db-library like PDO and build parameterized queries. It might me sufficient to escape single quotes within the variable with another single quote like this:

```
function mssql_escape($str) {
    return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
```

Comment: I added another possible solution(Edit)

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee'. ) )

Comment: I changed the double quotes with the single quotes and its worked. Thanks Daniel

Comment: Both provided solutions should result in exactly the same manner.

Comment: My next problem now are the columns which have spaces between them. For example First Name and Last Name as in ($rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt);
  while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)) {
      echo $obj->First Name.", ".$obj->Last Name."<br />";
})

Comment: If you need to stick to the column names (otherwise you should eliminate all those spaces) you can rename the columns within your query: `SELECT [First Name] AS firstName, [Last Name] AS lastName FROM  Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee]`

Comment: My next problem is with the WHERE clause. Suppose I want to select First Name and Last Name from Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee] where the E-mail is = a form field ($_GET['email']) or Employee Number = 13

Comment: You should normaly open a new question for this, to give people the chance to answer you properly. (you should also consider marking a answer as "correct answer" if it helped you to solve your problem)
I'll add a solution to you problem to my answer for proper code formating.

Comment: @Danial @user3315848 was 'DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee' your table name, my table name is Staff so my query would be                                                                                             `'SELECT * FROM Dbo.[Staff]';`

Answer (score 1):

If there are spaces in the tablename you should run the query like this: 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES]";
Not sure what you are trying to do with $employee, because php sees it as a variable and tries to paste fill it in there (I think here $employee being NULL).

Comment: If however $employee is the name of the employee you want to get from the database you should use $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES] WHERE [Last Name] = '$employee'";

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Dbo.DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee";
```

with

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Dbo.[DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee]';
```

Because php thinks $Employee is a variable if you use double quotes. The [] is used to tell the database that the table name is `DATABASE COMPANY SERVICES$Employee` otherwise the space will indicate the start of another sql command or variable.

Try not to use spaces in table names btw, it avoids confusion.