# prepare->execute returns false

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I have a little problem in php/mySql.

Here is the code :

```
$updateLastchange = "UPDATE lastchange SET student = ? date = ? WHERE tutor= ? ";
$req = $db->prepare($updateLastchange);
if($req->execute(array($_SESSION['toHelp'], $date, $_SESSION['email'])))
{
    //some code that should be executed
}
```

You also have to know that "lastchange" actually contains the row where tutor = $_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['toHelp'] is defined and date is just a date("Y-m-d H:i:s") created a bit earlier.

The problem is that the execute returns false, and I have a syntax error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'date =
>   '2015-06-10 11:09:53' WHERE tutor= 'tutor''

I don't understand why ...

I use WAMP (I don't know if you need to know that).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Put a comma between both columns ?!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `,` in your query:

```
$updateLastchange = "UPDATE lastchange SET student = ?, date = ? WHERE tutor= ? ";
```

If you want to store a variable in your database, I think it is possible (though I haven't tried it yet):

```
$variable = '$variableYouWantToStore';
```

Just use a single tick (`'`), not double tick(`"`), when doing this. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402566/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php).

Comment: Thank you ! I feel a bit stupid ... Just one question : is it possible to update a table whose name is a variable ? Like "UPDATE ? SET ..." with a execute later ?

Comment: @Raphallal if my answer did help you, you can upvote or mark my answer as the correct one. And I did update my answer regarding the storing of variable name.

Comment: I mean, I want my table name to be a variable... And I couldn't set your answer as "accepted" because I had to wait for 7 minutes.

Comment: @Raphallal - yes, you can do a query where the table name is coming from a variable. `"UPDATE ".$tablename." SET column1 = ? WHERE id = ?"`