# Cant find MySQL row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to get a MySQL row count  and I keep getting nothing instead. I keep getting the error

> "Error: couldn't find the row.". When in fact the row is really there in database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE code = '$promo'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $rowhis = $result->fetch_assoc();
} else {
    echo "Error: couldn't find the row.";
    die();
}
```

Comment: You Should look this first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402566/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php)

Comment: Use prepared statements.  This would help solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may request to follow PHP appending string with php variable.Please reffer this get more [idea](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Here you just change your query like below given

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE code = '".$promo."'";
```

Please try this will help you.