# PHP Parameterized mysql statement with LIKE clause returns command out of sync

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use a LIKE clause with a parameterized query with php and mysql. Every time I try though, I'm getting different errors.

I've tried to implement solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583336/how-do-i-create-a-pdo-parameterized-query-with-a-like-statement), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869676/parameterized-queries-php-mysql?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843640/like-operator-with-variable). Each of these is throwing different errors, so I'm afraid the problem is in something that I'm missing. If I try with an array in the execute function, I get Command out of sync error. When I try binding values or parameters, I'm getting a can't bind on string error.

I'm at a loss for what I'm missing.

Thanks for any help!

```
 <? 
    $access = 3;
    $dbConnect = true;
    require "../scripts/php/scriptSecurity.php";

    // Partial name given by user.
    $namePart = $_GET["namePart"];

    // Deal with name parts. last, first middle or first middle last, or first last
    if (strpos($namePart, ',') !== false){
        $arr_name = explode(",", $namePart);
        $lName = $arr_name[0];
        if (strpos($arr_name[1], " ") !== false){
            $firstName = substr($arr_name[1], 0, strpos($arr_name[1], " ", 1));
            $middleName = substr($arr_name[1], strpos($arr_name[1], " ", 1));
        }
    }
    elseif (strpos($namePart, " ") !== false){
        $arr_name = explode(" ", $namePart);
        if (sizeOf($arr_name) == 3) {       
            $fName = $arr_name[0];
            $lName = $arr_name[3];
            $mName = $arr_name[2];
        }
        elseif (sizeOf(arr_name) == 2) {
            $fName = $arr_name[0];
            $lName = $arr_name[1];
            $mName = $arr_name[1];
        }
        else {
            $fName = $namePart;
            $mName = $namePart;
            $lName = $namePart;
        }
    }
    else {
        $fName = $namePart;
        $lName = $namePart;
        $mName = $namePart;
    }
    // Get rid of extra spaces.
    $fName = str_replace(" ", "", $fName);
    $lName = str_replace(" ", "", $lName);
    $mName = str_replace(" ", "", $mName);
    // build query
    $query = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, StudentId, Gender, Grade, GradYear FROM students WHERE LastName LIKE ? OR FirstName LIKE ? OR MiddleName LIKE ? ORDER BY LastName, FirstName LIMIT 20";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
    // execute
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$lName.'%', '%'.$fName.'%', '%'.$mName.'%'));
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    // post results
    if (!$result) {
        echo $connect->error;
        echo "No Results";
    }
    else {
        echo "Results";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
                <div><? echo $row["LastName"] . ", " . $row["FirstName"] . "(" . $row["StudentId"] . ")"?> </div>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the string in param  with  wildchar in wrong way  you can use a simplest way  managing  the wildchar with concat and assign the pure var as param

```
  $query = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, StudentId, Gender, Grade, GradYear 
  FROM students 
  WHERE LastName LIKE concat('%',?, '%') 
  OR FirstName LIKE concat('%',?, '%')
  OR MiddleName LIKE concat('%',?, '%')
  ORDER BY LastName, FirstName 
  LIMIT 20";
  $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
  // execute
  $stmt->execute(array($lName, $fName, $mName));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this and am now getting:

Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Comment: you missed  lastname  column name ..  before where .. add the missing code  ..  and why downvote ???

Comment: Ok...so I had a mistake in the code. Just fixed that, and now I'm getting results, but I'm only getting results for the first character. If the $namePart is one character, I get the top twenty results with that character. When I type a second character, I'm not getting an error, but I'm getting no results.

Comment: for this you should check  you code before the query  and  this seems another problem  respect tom your original question

Comment: Yes. True. I'll post separately. It is a new problem. I just hate fixing one problem only to be introduced to the next...*sigh. Thanks again for the help.