# SQL LIKE not searching

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to find a value from my database using SQL `LIKE`:

```
SELECT id FROM titles WHERE skuid LIKE '%:cusa%'
```

Where `:cusa` is defined `CUSA06536` as a dynamic value in my PHP code.

It should return:

[image]

But instead it returns nothing. No errors are outputted. Am I doing something wrong? Are dynamic values not supported?

---

PHP script:

```
public function findCusa($cusa) {
    $find = $this->query("SELECT id FROM titles WHERE skuid LIKE '%:cusa%'");
    $find->execute(array(":cusa" => $cusa));

    if($find->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'found!';
    }

    echo 'not found';
}
```

Then called as `$ps->findCusa('CUSA06536');` which returns not found.

Comment: Include your PHP script.  It sounds like you're not correctly binding the `:cusa` variable.  *(`SELECT id FROM titles WHERE skuid LIKE '%CUSA06536%'` should work fine.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIKE operator with $variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843640/like-operator-with-variable)

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated the question.

Comment: if your ":cusa" mean the parameter, than you need something like '%' + :cusa + '%'.

Comment: @P.Waksman That tells me I have an error in my syntax.

Comment: scaisEdge got it, also the Karol Dowbecki has nice answer. At least for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the `%` in the `LIKE` statement, instead do it in the PHP code. Most likely your DB framework is getting confused when you use a quoted bind parameter.

```
$find = $this->query("SELECT id FROM titles WHERE skuid LIKE :cusa");
$find->execute(array(":cusa" => '%' . $cusa . '%'));
```

Comment: True, I added it in the query itself. This works, accepted!

Answer (score 1):

try using a proper string eg: using concat

```
    ("SELECT id FROM titles WHERE skuid LIKE concat('%', :cusa, '%')");
```