# updating data in mysql database using arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to update information that is already in the database, but using an array.  I get 'successfully update' message white the data in the database is not updated.

the following is the function I use to do the insertion:

```
function update_knowledge_modules($update_data,$value)
{   
    $update = array();
    array_walk($update_data,'array_clean');

    foreach($update_data as $field=>$data)
    {
        $update[] = '.$field. = \''.$data.'\'';
    }



    $query = "UPDATE knowledge_modules SET".implode(', ',$update)."WHERE curr_code =$value";

    mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error);

}

<?php

                    if(isset($_GET['success']) == true && empty($_GET['success'])==true)
                        {
                            echo 'Changed successfully';    
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            if(empty($_POST)== false && empty($errors)== true ) 
                                {
                                    $update_module = array(
                                    'KM_Number'=>$_POST['KM_Number'],
                                    'KM_Title'=>$_POST['KM_Title'],
                                    'NQF_Level'=>$_POST['NQF_Level'],
                                    'Credits'=>$_POST['Credits']


                                    );

                                    update_knowledge_modules($update_module,$_SESSION['Curr_Code']); 
                                    header('Location:edit_km_details.php?success');
                                    exit();
                                }
                        else if(empty($errors)== false)
                            {
                                echo output($errors);
                            }

              ?>

            <form action="edit_km_details.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: `$update[] = '.$field. = \''.$data.'\'';` will output the text "$field2" not the content of the `$field` variable, try `$update[] = "$field = '$data'";` instead?

Comment: Have you echoed out the query to make sure it is correct?

Comment: Can you post example of final query that you run. `$query`

Comment: yes, @Stu thats the output I get, but I would like to get the content instead

Comment: I just got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.$field. = '120399111-KM-01', .$field. = 'skdjfas', .$field. = 'l5', .$field. = ' at line 1

Comment: `$update[] = "$field = '$data'";` or `$update[] = $field.' = "'.$data.'"';` might work for you. As for using quotes you might want to read this: [PHP: different quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318028/php-different-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you are outputting the "changed successfully" message solely based on `$_GET['success']` being truthy. It has nothing to do with whether you had success or failure in your `update_knowledge_modules` function call at all, which seems odd.

Second of all, I don't see anywhere where you are actually making a database connection.

Third, your query is undoubtedly being formed improperly.  Look at this:

```
$update[] = '.$field. = \''.$data.'\'';
```

you are going to get a literal `$field` and backslashes in your query string.  Try this:

```
$update[] = $field . " = '" . $data . "'";
```

Also where you put your imploded array in the final query, you don't have spaces after `SET` and before `WHERE`.

Anytime you are having problems with a query, just `var_dump` it and run it on the database directly to see why it isn't working and look at your errors, including mysql errors.

Finally, you should not be using the `mysql_*` family of functions. They are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$update[] = $field . " = '" . $data . "'";`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => KM_Number = 'blah'
)
```