# PHP - Add null character to string

Tags: php, string, null, padding

I'm trying to append a number of NULL characters '\0' to a string in PHP.

```
$s = 'hello';
while(strlen($s) < 32) $s .= '\0';
```

However, PHP adds 2 characters (\ and 0), instead of escaping the character and adding NULL. Does anyone know to add a NULL character to a string?

Comment: `.= null;` maybe? Will result in an endless loop though.

Comment: Nope, adding null does not increase the string length. Hence, the loop is infinite.

Comment: There is no NULL character in this world

Comment: `str_pad($s, 32, "\0");`

Comment: single quoted strings do not interpret most \ escape sequences. '\0' is literally the string \0, whereas "\0" is the null character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if `\0` is correct in your case, but you should use `"`:

```
$s = 'hello';
while(strlen($s) < 32) $s .= "\0";
```

Comment: well, well, well. That worked. I thought ' and " are synonyms in PHP?

Comment: Here is some further explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318028/php-different-quotes

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new.

Answer (score 4):

Caused by ' you should use ".

Using simple quote PHP doesn't interpret code or special char like (\n\r\0), by using double quote PHP will.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work:

```
$result = str_pad($str, 32, "\0");
echo strlen($result); // output: 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

`echo $str="Hello ";
echo ' Length : '.strlen($str);
while(strlen($str)<32)
{
    $str.='  ';
}
echo '<br/>';
echo $str;
echo ' Length : '.strlen($str);`

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just the following line is enough:

```
$s = pack('a32', 'hello');
```