# replace 2 newlines with one - php preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am triyng to replace 2 or more newlines with just 1 using PHP's `preg_replace()` function

```
$entry = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', '\n', $entry);
```

However it replaces it with a "\n" instead of a newline. I mean, it sees \n as a normal string with two letters. What should i do?

Comment: That's how PHP interprets strings within single quotation marks. You need double quotes around `\n`.

Comment: You have to read php basics about [strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: [It works if you use "\n" as the replacement](http://rextester.com/DHYK89462).

Comment: @revo damn! how could i know that? if you add an answer i'll accept it. I tihnk question will be helpful for some.

Comment: This question is a subject of lots of questions.

Answer (score 0):

In php, there are some differences between double quotes and single quotes: [PHP: different quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318028/php-different-quotes). To answer your question, all you need to do is replace the single quotes with double quotes as shown here:

```
$entry = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n", $entry);
```

You can read all about strings in php in the documentation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php